# Converting an entity object - column to row and regroup - C# Linq

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I am getting an entity object as below:

```
{qid=1110, cid=94, gid=3, sid=10, cs=6}
{qid=1110, cid=95, gid=3, sid=10, cs=4}
{qid=1110, cid=96, gid=3, sid=10, cs=6}
{qid=1110, cid=97, gid=3, sid=10, cs=0}
{qid=1111, cid=94, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5}
{qid=1111, cid=95, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5}
{qid=1111, cid=96, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5}
{qid=1111, cid=97, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5}
{qid=1110, cid=94, gid=4, sid=10, cs=6}
{qid=1110, cid=95, gid=4, sid=10, cs=4}
{qid=1110, cid=96, gid=4, sid=10, cs=6}
{qid=1110, cid=97, gid=4, sid=10, cs=4}
```

But I need to display or convert it as follows:

```
qid || cid1cs || cid2cs || cid3cs || cid4cs || avg_cs || gid || sid
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1110||    6   ||    4   ||    6   ||     0  ||   4    || 3   || 10
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1110||    6   ||    4   ||    6   ||     4  ||   5    || 4   || 10
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1111||    5   ||    5   ||    5   ||     5  ||   5    || 3   || 10
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

where cid1cs is the cs of cid=94 , cid2cs= cs of 95 and so on..
avg_cs is the avg of all 4 cs (cid1cs, cid2cs..) and the grouping and ordering need to be performed on gid, sid and qid.

Is it possible to do it in LINQ ? I am using C#

Can anybody help pls?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course it is possible, have you tried doing this?

Comment: What happens if there are more than 4 rows of 1 qid value?

Comment: No there will not be more than 4 rows for each qid, that is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a example for you, but remember, this is very **error prone**! But it works. When there are less rows than 4, it will fail.

I think there is a better implementation for the GetHashCode(), but this will work.

```
    public class Triplet : IEquatable<Triplet>
    {
        public int Value1 { get; set; }
        public int Value2 { get; set; }
        public int Value3 { get; set; }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Value1.GetHashCode() + Value2.GetHashCode() + Value3.GetHashCode();
        }

        public bool Equals(Triplet other)
        {
            int d1 = this.Value1.CompareTo(other.Value1);
            if (d1 != 0)
                return false;

            int d2 = this.Value2.CompareTo(other.Value2);
            if (d2 != 0)
                return false;

            int d3 = this.Value3.CompareTo(other.Value3);
            if (d3 != 0)
                return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

this linq code:

```
        var data = new[] 
        {
            new {qid=1110, cid=94, gid=3, sid=10, cs=6},
            new {qid=1110, cid=95, gid=3, sid=10, cs=4},
            new {qid=1110, cid=96, gid=3, sid=10, cs=6},
            new {qid=1110, cid=97, gid=3, sid=10, cs=0},
            new {qid=1111, cid=94, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5},
            new {qid=1111, cid=95, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5},
            new {qid=1111, cid=96, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5},
            new {qid=1111, cid=97, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5},
            new {qid=1110, cid=94, gid=4, sid=10, cs=6},
            new {qid=1110, cid=95, gid=4, sid=10, cs=4},
            new {qid=1110, cid=96, gid=4, sid=10, cs=6},
            new {qid=1110, cid=97, gid=4, sid=10, cs=4}
        };

        var avg = from item in data
                  group item by new Triplet { Value1 = item.qid, Value2 = item.gid, Value3 = item.sid } into groupedItems
                  select new
                  {
                      qid = groupedItems.Key,
                      cid1cs = groupedItems.First().cs,
                      cid2cs = groupedItems.Skip(1).First().cs,
                      cid3cs = groupedItems.Skip(2).First().cs,
                      cid4cs = groupedItems.Skip(3).First().cs,
                      avg_cs = groupedItems.Average(i => i.cs),
                      gid = groupedItems.First().gid,
                      sid = groupedItems.First().sid
                  };
```

Comment: Hmm, i see my code only returns 2 results, because it's grouping all _qid_'s.?

Comment: Ok, thanks Jeroen van Langen , it is done, when I started worked with your first code, I did the same as you have done in the next edition, only diff I did not create any Triplet class, but simply grouped it with item.qid,item.gid,item.sid and it worked greatly...a small modification I also made I checked whether the result exists or not? with groupedItems.Skip(n).Any() and it is working now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First off, LINQPad is your friend, download it, use it, you'll love it. It contains many examples and teaches you more about LINQ.

In regards to your grouping/crosstab question:

```
var data = new[] 
{
    new {qid=1110, cid=94, gid=3, sid=10, cs=6},
    new {qid=1110, cid=95, gid=3, sid=10, cs=4},
    new {qid=1110, cid=96, gid=3, sid=10, cs=6},
    new {qid=1110, cid=97, gid=3, sid=10, cs=0},
    new {qid=1111, cid=94, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5},
    new {qid=1111, cid=95, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5},
    new {qid=1111, cid=96, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5},
    new {qid=1111, cid=97, gid=3, sid=10, cs=5},
    new {qid=1110, cid=94, gid=4, sid=10, cs=6},
    new {qid=1110, cid=95, gid=4, sid=10, cs=4},
    new {qid=1110, cid=96, gid=4, sid=10, cs=6},
    new {qid=1110, cid=97, gid=4, sid=10, cs=4}
};

var query = from item in data
            group item by new { qid = item.qid, gid = item.gid, sid = item.sid } into grouped
            select new
            {
                qid = grouped.Key.qid,
                cid1cs = grouped.Where(item => item.cid == 94).Sum(item => item.cs),
                cid2cs = grouped.Where(item => item.cid == 95).Sum(item => item.cs),
                cid3cs = grouped.Where(item => item.cid == 96).Sum(item => item.cs),
                cid4cs = grouped.Where(item => item.cid == 97).Sum(item => item.cs),
                avg_cs = grouped.Average(item => item.cs),
                gid = grouped.Key.gid,
                sid = grouped.Key.sid
            };
query.Dump();
```

That last line is how you output the results in LINQPad, just so you can see the results is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom equality comparer, here is an example:

```
  class Program
  {
    public class MyClass
    {
      public int qid { get; set; }
      public int cid { get; set; }
      public int gid { get; set; }
      public int sid { get; set; }
      public int cs { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClassComaparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
    {

      public bool Equals(MyClass x, MyClass y)
      {
        return x.qid == y.qid && x.gid == y.gid && x.sid == y.sid;
      }

      public int GetHashCode(MyClass obj)
      {
        return obj.qid;
      }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var list = new List<MyClass>();
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1110, cid = 94, gid = 3, sid = 10, cs = 6 });
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1110, cid = 95, gid = 3, sid = 10, cs = 4 });
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1110, cid = 96, gid = 3, sid = 10, cs = 6 });
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1110, cid = 97, gid = 3, sid = 10, cs = 0 });
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1111, cid = 94, gid = 3, sid = 10, cs = 5 });
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1111, cid = 95, gid = 3, sid = 10, cs = 5 });
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1111, cid = 96, gid = 3, sid = 10, cs = 5 });
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1111, cid = 97, gid = 3, sid = 10, cs = 5 });
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1110, cid = 94, gid = 4, sid = 10, cs = 6 });
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1110, cid = 95, gid = 4, sid = 10, cs = 4 });
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1110, cid = 96, gid = 4, sid = 10, cs = 6 });
      list.Add(new MyClass() { qid = 1110, cid = 97, gid = 4, sid = 10, cs = 4 });

      var result = list.GroupBy(w => w, new MyClassComaparer()).Select(w => new
                  {
                    qid = w.Key.qid,
                    cid1cs = w.Where(e => e.cid == 94).Sum(e => e.cs),
                    cid2cs = w.Where(e => e.cid == 95).Sum(e => e.cs),
                    cid3cs = w.Where(e => e.cid == 96).Sum(e => e.cs),
                    cid4cs = w.Where(e => e.cid == 97).Sum(e => e.cs),                    
                    avg_cs = w.Average(i => i.cs),
                    gid = w.Key.gid,
                    sid = w.Key.sid
                  }).ToList();

      Console.ReadKey();
    }   
  }
```